# Microsoft Graph API for messages return empty values when sort using receivedDateTime

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We are developing an application to get the emails of users, we need to process the older emails first, for that we are using the *$orderby* for the property *receivedDateTime*. Following is the actual API call we make

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/admin@test.com/messages?$orderby=receivedDateTime+ASC
```

it is working fine for majority of users, but for very few users if we do API calls like the above it returns 200 response with no email messages in body, even-though they have emails in their mailbox.

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('admin%40test.com')/messages","value":[]}
```

The above is the response we get for those users

But if we try order by *DESC* it is working fine. We are using the client credentials flow for token generation.

Comment: Could you explain why you're passing the param `$filter=receivedDateTime+gt+1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`?

Comment: I tried the API without that filter condition, that isn't working, I will modify the question without the filter

Comment: I got the this exact issue as well. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @DorShemer, I didn't get any solution yet, there might be some emails, which breaks the API calls. I tried the API calls without filter, there also I faced similar kind of issue like, a user has 16000 emails but microsoft returns only 6000 using _messages_ endpoint.

Comment: @DorShemer, Did you get any solution for this problem? Please update me.

Comment: @GokulnathK Afraid not, ended up switching to receivedDateTime desc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the REST API below to check if it works.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/admin@example.com/messages?$orderby=receivedDateTime
```

And check if the receivedDateTime values of the messages > "1970-01-01".

Comment: I tried, that also not working, the API call fails if I try receivedDateTime sorting in ascending order

Comment: Do you have any other solution for this problem?